# Spinner object doesn't take second input once a process is being executed

Tags: android, android-spinner, yahoo-finance

I am working on a finance app where i am populating the exchange currecny value using the [Yahoo Finance Api](http://yahoofinance-api.com) and here is my implementation

```
void currency_widget() {
    from.setAdapter(new CurrencyListAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.country_list_item, recourseList));
    from.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            String m = (String) Array.get(recourseList, i);
            String[] ma = m.split(",");
            Locale locale = new Locale("en_US", ma[1]);
            c2 = Currency.getInstance(locale);
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {
        }
    });


    to.setAdapter(new CurrencyListAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.country_list_item, recourseList));
    to.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            String m = (String) Array.get(recourseList, i);
            String[] ma = m.split(",");
            Locale locale = new Locale("en_US", ma[1]);
            c1 = Currency.getInstance(locale);
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {
        }
    });


}

public class connection extends AsyncTask {
    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground(Object... arg0) {
        connect();
        return null;
    }

    private void connect() {
        try {
            String as = c2 + "" + c1 + "=" + "X";
            // FxQuote ab=YahooFinance.getFx(FxSymbols.)
            FxQuote usdeur = null;
            try {
                usdeur = YahooFinance.getFx(as);
                edittxt.setText("" + usdeur);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                edittxt.setText("No Internet Connection");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

In this I have two spinner object which allows the user to select their desired currency  `from` is the first spinner object and `to` is the second spinner object.

This far everything works fine as expected. **The problem arises when I click the get button and execute the operation**

```
get.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            new connection().execute(); //TODO Spinner won't take second time input
        }
    });
```

It display the value too, but if I try to change the spinner items for the second time it does not reflect anything i.e lets say I clicked on the spinner and the drop down menu appeared but and i changed the value but it won't show the item the selection process is done and the dropdown button is closed hence the spinner items fix to the first position

> **Solved**

Changed the code as per the answer received and it worked

```
@Override
    protected Object doInBackground(Object... arg0) {
       // connect();
        String as = c2 + "" + c1 + "=" + "X";
       // FxQuote usdeur = YahooFinance.getFx(as);
        return YahooFinance.getFx(as);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Object o) {
        super.onPostExecute(o);
        try {
            edittxt.setText("" + o);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            edittxt.setText("No Internet Connection");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didnt checked all your code but i saw that you are calling

`edittxt.setText("No Internet Connection");` on `doInBackground()` which is wrong.

You have to `setText` on `postExecute()` which runs on `UI-Thread`.

Return `usdeur` on `doInBackground()` and `setText` on `postExecute()`

Comment: sir, i understand what you are saying but we perform that when we are returning anything from the `doInBackground()`, but here i am performing everything within the `doInBackground()` method, i will give it a try, the solution that you have suggested and will let you know

Comment: as `doInBackground()` works on background thread. When you are changing your `Spinner` value for the second time, again it works in another thread while the first one still working maybe. Just give it a try, bcs probably thats what it is causing it.

Comment: I think hrskrs is right, please check this link http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html the first code shows you how to use the postExecute method.

Comment: sir, your solution did work but where do i put the exception? well i gave it in the `postExecute()` method but it returns `null`

Comment: why puttin an `exeption`?  If you want to do so, you can put it wherever you want to `catch` it